# How to work with webhooks in PHP

Tags: php, post, webhooks

I'm working with Paymill as my payment provider and i'm getting stuck with the Webhooks.

Currently i recieve the webhook by email as per the below but I want to pick this up in a page instead and post it to my database. I know how to do this bit, however i'm unsure how i pick up to pick up the individual posts.

```
{
    "event_type":"transaction.created",
    "event_resource":{
        "id":"tran_9x2x8xex5x7xexex0x8x9xexexbx",
        "amount":"9980",
        "origin_amount":9980,
        "status":"open",
        "description":"9xax1x7x5x8x2xaxaxcx4x5xfx8x2x2x",
        "livemode":true,
        "refunds":null,
        "currency":"GBP",
        "created_at":1375307922,
        "updated_at":1375307922,
        "response_code":10001,
        "short_id":null,
        "is_fraud":false,
        "invoices":[

        ],
        "app_id":null,
        "fees":[

        ],
        "payment":{
            "id":"pay_7xdxex9xfxcx6x3x9x5x7xcx",
            "type":"creditcard",
            "client":"client_2x2xex0x2x4xx3bx3x6x",
            "card_type":"mastercard",
            "country":null,
            "expire_month":"10",
            "expire_year":"2015",
            "card_holder":"XXX XXXXXX",
            "last4":"8XX8",
            "created_at":1375307921,
            "updated_at":1375307922,
            "app_id":null
        },
        "client":{
            "id":"client_2x2xex0x2x4xfx3x3x6x",
            "email":null,
            "description":null,
            "created_at":1375307922,
            "updated_at":1375307922,
            "app_id":null,
            "payment":[

            ],
            "subscription":null
        },
        "preauthorization":null
    },
    "created_at":1375307922,
    "app_id":null
}
```

So how do I pull out using php the event_resource id?

Normally i would just do `<?php $_POST['event_resource]; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a JSON object, so use `json_decode()` to convert it into a nice PHP object.

```
$reply = json_decode( $data_from_hook );
```

SAMPLE CODE:

```
<?php


    $t = '{
    "event_type":"transaction.created",
    "event_resource":{
        "id":"tran_9x2x8xex5x7xexex0x8x9xexexbx",
        "amount":"9980",
        "origin_amount":9980,
        "status":"open",
        "description":"9xax1x7x5x8x2xaxaxcx4x5xfx8x2x2x",
        "livemode":true,
        "refunds":null,
        "currency":"GBP",
        "created_at":1375307922,
        "updated_at":1375307922,
        "response_code":10001,
        "short_id":null,
        "is_fraud":false,
        "invoices":[

        ],
        "app_id":null,
        "fees":[

        ],
        "payment":{
            "id":"pay_7xdxex9xfxcx6x3x9x5x7xcx",
            "type":"creditcard",
            "client":"client_2x2xex0x2x4xx3bx3x6x",
            "card_type":"mastercard",
            "country":null,
            "expire_month":"10",
            "expire_year":"2015",
            "card_holder":"XXX XXXXXX",
            "last4":"8XX8",
            "created_at":1375307921,
            "updated_at":1375307922,
            "app_id":null
        },
        "client":{
            "id":"client_2x2xex0x2x4xfx3x3x6x",
            "email":null,
            "description":null,
            "created_at":1375307922,
            "updated_at":1375307922,
            "app_id":null,
            "payment":[

            ],
            "subscription":null
        },
        "preauthorization":null
    },
    "created_at":1375307922,
    "app_id":null
}';





echo PHP_EOL;
$u = json_decode($t);
print_r( $u );

echo 'Event Rosource ID = ' . $u->event_resource->id;
```

RESULTS:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [event_type] => transaction.created
    [event_resource] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => tran_9x2x8xex5x7xexex0x8x9xexexbx
            [amount] => 9980
            [origin_amount] => 9980
            [status] => open
            [description] => 9xax1x7x5x8x2xaxaxcx4x5xfx8x2x2x
            [livemode] => 1
            [refunds] =>
            [currency] => GBP
            [created_at] => 1375307922
            [updated_at] => 1375307922
            [response_code] => 10001
            [short_id] =>
            [is_fraud] =>
            [invoices] => Array
                (
                )

            [app_id] =>
            [fees] => Array
                (
                )

            [payment] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => pay_7xdxex9xfxcx6x3x9x5x7xcx
                    [type] => creditcard
                    [client] => client_2x2xex0x2x4xx3bx3x6x
                    [card_type] => mastercard
                    [country] =>
                    [expire_month] => 10
                    [expire_year] => 2015
                    [card_holder] => XXX XXXXXX
                    [last4] => 8XX8
                    [created_at] => 1375307921
                    [updated_at] => 1375307922
                    [app_id] =>
                )

            [client] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => client_2x2xex0x2x4xfx3x3x6x
                    [email] =>
                    [description] =>
                    [created_at] => 1375307922
                    [updated_at] => 1375307922
                    [app_id] =>
                    [payment] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [subscription] =>
                )

            [preauthorization] =>
        )

    [created_at] => 1375307922
    [app_id] =>
)


Event Rosource ID = tran_9x2x8xex5x7xexex0x8x9xexexbx
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get the you the json:

```
$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($body, true);
```